# ipyparallel strange overhead behavior

Tags: python, parallel-processing, cluster-computing, overhead

Im trying to understand how to do distributed processing with ipyparallel and jupyter notebook, so i did some test and got odd results.

```
from ipyparallel import Client
%px import numpy as np

rc = Client()
dview = rc[:]
bview = rc.load_balanced_view()

print(len(dview))
print(len(bview))

data = [np.random.rand(10000)] * 4

%time np.sin(data)

%%time #45.7ms
results = dview.map(np.sin, data)
results.get()

%%time #110ms
dview.push({'data': data})
%px results = np.sin(data)
results

%%time #4.9ms
results = np.sin(data)
results

%%time #93ms
results = bview.map(np.sin, data)
results.get()
```

What is the matter with the overhead?
Is the task i/o bound in this case and just 1 core can do it better?
I tried larger arrays and still got better times with no parallel processing.

Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be the io. Push pushes the whole set of data to every node. I am not sure about the map function, but most likely it splits the data in chunks that are sent to nodes. So smaller chunks - faster processing. Load balancer most likely sends the data and the task two time to the same node, which significantly hits performance.

And how did you manage to send the data in 40 ms? I am used to http protocol where only the handshake takes about a second. For me 40 ms in the network is lightning fast.

EDIT About long times (40ms):

In local networks the ping time of 1-10ms is considered a normal situation. Taking into account that you first need to make a handshake (minimum 2 signals) and only then send the data (minimum 1 signal) and wait for the response (another signal) you already talk about 20ms just for connecting two computers. Of course you can try to minimize the ping time to 1ms and then use a faster MPI protocol. But as I understand it does not improve the situation significantly. Only one order of magnitude faster.

Therefore the general recommendations are to use larger jobs. For example, a pretty fast dask distributed framework (faster than Celery based on benchmarks) recommends tasks times to be more than 100ms. Otherwise the overhead of the framework starts overweighting the time of the execution and the parallelization benefits are disappearing. [Efficiency on Dask Distributed](http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/efficiency.html)

Comment: It is running on local machine. the nodes are just engines running at the same machine.

Comment: But Ipyparallel still uses ZeroMQ protocol. Theoretically you should be able to speed it up by using MPI.

Comment: "I am not sure about the map function" – then why are you answering this question. `DirectView.map` performs one computation for each value, and distributes them over the engines.

Comment: Because I see the same distributed behavior for dask and spark.